# How do react useEffect hook execute re-render based on dependency list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Do react useEffect hook also cache dependency list values like how useMemo does there by comparing and re-render?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @AtifSaddique any valid source or documentation ?

Comment: You can read comments on following github issue, its not directly related to your question, but it will answer your question.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14324